# MySQL count total records come with same seller

Tags: mysql, count

I have below query to listed order items, and need to count how many item are from same seller,

As illustrate, I want to know 3 items are from **Seller A** and 2 from **Seller B**, is it possible?

[image]

```
SELECT 
    a.order_id,
    a.seller_id,
    a.pid,
    a.sum_price,
    x.checkout_method,
    x.total_payment,
    x.shipment_rate, 
    x.remarks
FROM lodge a 
JOIN transaction x ON a.order_id = x.order_id 
WHERE a.order_id = 'XYZ1234' 
AND x.acct_id = '123'
```

I try `count(*)` and `GROUP BY` in same query, but only 2 results has return.

```
SELECT 
    count(*),
    a.order_id,
    a.seller_id,
    a.pid,
    a.sum_price,
    x.checkout_method,
    x.total_payment,
    x.shipment_rate, 
    x.remarks
FROM lodge a 
JOIN transaction x ON a.order_id = x.order_id 
WHERE a.order_id = 'XYZ1234' 
AND x.acct_id = '123'
GROUP BY a.seller_id
```

Comment: Could you also post what the output should look like. Since group by in your case gives just 2 records.

Comment: *"I try `count(*)` and `GROUP BY` in same query, but only 2 results has return."* -- this is how `GROUP BY` works. It doesn't return rows from the database, it computes rows and returns them. One row from a group of rows read from the database, all of them having the same value in `a.seller_id`. One row in the output for the yellow group of rows, one row in the output for the green group of rows.

Comment: @axiac, exactly